# How to get Insets if no Renderer exists

Tags: java, swing, renderer, insets

If the JTable's cells have an associated Renderer I am able to get the insets.

```
:
int x = ((JComponent)myRenderer).getInsets().left)
:
:
int x = ((JComponent)myRenderer).getInsets().right)
:
```

I have specific code to verify if the call from `getCellRenderer()` returns a null and it does. 
When this occurs I am uncertain how the Insets can be retrieved?

Comment: Why do you think you need the insets? What is the problem that you are trying to solve. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. One line of code does not help.

Comment: Trying to calculate the true available space within a cell which will be used for other calculations. If the cell width is 50 but the left and right Insets are 5 each then the "true" cell with is 40 (not 50).

Comment: Ok, so post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. If you set the Border properly as asked on your previous question, I don't see what the problem is. The default renderer uses a JLabel which does not have a Border. `When this occurs I am uncertain how the Insets can be retrieved?` Then the Insets will be 0.

Comment: Won't the size of the cell be determined by the `TableColumn`?  You could also use the preferredSize of the cell renderer's component, which, if written correctly, will take into consideration the insets...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will research more in depth shortly as I have a few things in the works to test out. I have a small sample, but it works (Arrrgggh...I hate when that happens). The actual application is doing something usual that I will have to track down.